# Is there an easier way to use Windows ctrl+v (paste) functionality in a C# Console application?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, c#-2.0, console-application

I’ve build a console application that has a command interpreter. To make things easier I needed to add support for reading the clipboard when **ctrl+v** is pressed. When I press ctrl+v I see the symbol **^V** in the console, so I’m replacing that character with the clipboard text. After some googling I’ve found out that the clipboard can be accessed by System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.GetText().

My question is: **Is there a better solution to add clipboard support to a console application? Possibly without using System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard? Maybe an interop call can do the trick?**

One of the drawbacks of this solution is that the clipboard only works when the thread is defined as [STAThread]. It would also be a lot nicer if I could get rid of the ^V symbol.

This is the code of the current solution:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        public static readonly string ClipboardChar = Convert.ToChar(22).ToString();

        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("Do some pastin': ");

            //read
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
            string result = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.ResetColor();

            //read keyboard
            if (result.Contains(ClipboardChar))
            {
                result = result.Replace(ClipboardChar, Clipboard.GetText());
            }

            //write result
            Console.WriteLine("\nResult: ");
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White; 
            Console.WriteLine(result);
            Console.ResetColor();

            Console.WriteLine("\nPress any key to continue...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why... you don't want any reference to System.Windows.Forms? It's a standard .NET library, so your application won't get bigger when deployed. And if you use any other method, the startup of your application will be slower anyway

Comment: How would it be slower? I've added some drawbacks of the current solution to the question: One of the drawbacks of this solution is that the clipboard only works when the thread is defined as [STAThread]. It would also be a lot nicer if I could get rid of the ^V symbol.

Comment: on different note, you may find these articles on extending console api by .NET useful: http://www.devsource.com/c/a/Using-VS/Console-Input-in-NET/, http://www.devsource.com/c/a/Using-VS/Working-with-Console-Screen-Buffers-in-NET/1/

Comment: @VinayC thanks man. Good to have some readin'!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can certainly use P/Invoke to do this. Please treat the sample code as proof-of-concept as it was rapidly cobbled together & tested. I've taken a few liberties - for instance my prototype for `GlobalLock` returns `string` although the Win API really returns `LPVOID`.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace clipboard
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ConsoleKeyInfo ki = Console.ReadKey( true );
            if( ( ki.Key == ConsoleKey.V ) && ( ki.Modifiers == ConsoleModifiers.Control ) )
            {
                Console.WriteLine( "Ctrl+V pressed" );
                string s = ClipBoard.PasteTextFromClipboard();
                Console.WriteLine( s );
            }

            Console.Write("Press any key to continue . . . ");
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
    }

    class ClipBoard
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern Int32 IsClipboardFormatAvailable( uint format );

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern Int32 OpenClipboard( IntPtr hWndNewOwner );

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr GetClipboardData( uint uFormat );

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern Int32 CloseClipboard();

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern Int32 GlobalLock( IntPtr hMem );

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern Int32 GlobalUnlock( IntPtr hMem );

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        public static extern UIntPtr GlobalSize(IntPtr hMem);

        const uint CF_TEXT = 1;

        public static string PasteTextFromClipboard()
        {
            string result = "";
            if( IsClipboardFormatAvailable( CF_TEXT ) == 0 )
            {
                return result; 
            }
            if( OpenClipboard((IntPtr)0) == 0 )
            {
                return result; 
            }

            IntPtr hglb = GetClipboardData(CF_TEXT);
            if( hglb != (IntPtr)0 )
            {
                UIntPtr size = GlobalSize(hglb);
                IntPtr s = GlobalLock(hglb);
                byte[] buffer = new byte[(int)size];
                Marshal.Copy(s, buffer, 0, (int)size);
                if (s != null)
                {
                    result = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer);
                    GlobalUnlock(hglb);
                }
            }

            CloseClipboard();
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks good... but now I need to look into the question of how to simulate the ReadLine() with ReadKey() :D

Comment: This P/Invoke also gets rid of the [STAThread] that was needed for System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard! :D

Comment: I LOVE YOU Man. Very Smart and effective. I got rid of forms for efficieny and I really hated the idea of kinda injecting them again. Thanx

Comment: @Mika Jacobi - No problem. Actually the edit by Community has cleaned-up my original code so my comments about 'taking liberties' no longer apply!

Answer (score 3):

If you click the icon in the top left corner of the console application window you get a 'Edit' | 'Paste' option.

Comment: Hahaha... yeah, but my users want the support over ctlr+v.

Comment: I think `Alt+Space, E, P` should be faster that clicking corner icon.